# Count unique data point in grouped data in R

Tags: r, unique

I've been searching for hours on SO and cannot find this solution.

I have the below data set:

```
   ID   RANK 
    1   1       
    1   3       
    1   3       
    1   4       
    2   2       
    2   3       
    2   3       
    2   3       
    3   1       
    4   2       
    4   2
```

I'm trying to group by ID and then produce a count of how many unique times the rank shows up within the group Id so the results

```
   ID   RANK  Unique
    1   1       1
    1   3       2
    1   3       2
    1   4       1
    2   2       1
    2   3       3
    2   3       3
    2   3       3
    3   1       1
    4   2       2
    4   2       2
```

I'm using this formula and it's just providing the result of what is in the RANK column

```
Unique <- with(DATA, RANK, ID, FUN = function(i) length((unique(i))))
```

Comment: With `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(ID, RANK) %>% mutate(Unique = n())` or base R: `df$Unique <- ave(df$ID, df$ID, df$RANK, FUN = length)` or `data.table`: `setDT(df)[, Unique := .N, by = .(ID, RANK)][]`

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution. Tabulates the number of items cross-classified by ID and RANK. The `ave` function is useful when you can identify one vector that need a f=unction applied within possibly multiple criteria but need the result to get distributed back into a dataframe: The `length` function is doing the counting:

```
> dat$UNIQUE <- with(dat, ave(ID, ID, RANK, FUN=length))
> dat
   ID RANK UNIQUE
1   1    1      1
2   1    3      2
3   1    3      2
4   1    4      1
5   2    2      1
6   2    3      3
7   2    3      3
8   2    3      3
9   3    1      1
10  4    2      2
11  4    2      2
```

When @hadley decided to redefine R in `dplyr`, he used `count` as the name of his equivalent function.